# Select all rows where all submitted checkbox values exist in comma separated strings in mySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, mysqli

I want to be able to `SELECT` only rows `WHERE` **all** the submitted `checkbox values` exist in `keyWords`. My code SELECTS rows with **any** of the submitted checkbox values.

I've got a mySQL database PhotoArchive with a table photos

```
| id  | title   |filePath      | keyWords              |
| 1   | mypic1  |imgs/pic1.jpg | Mono,Portrait (etc)   |
| 2   | mypic1  |imgs/pic2.jpg | Colour,Portrait (etc) |
| 3   | mypic2  |imgs/pic2.jpg | Mono,Landscape (etc)  |
| 4   | mypic2  |imgs/pic2.jpg | Colour,Landscape (etc)|
```

I've got a html page with a checkbox form

```
<form action="selectFromDb.php" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" value="Mono" name="category[]" id="OptMono" />
  <label for="OptMono"> Monochrome</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Colour" name="category[]" id="OptColour" />
  <label for="OptColour"> Colour</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Portraits" name="category[]" id="OptPortraits" />
  <label for="OptPortraits"> Portraits</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="Landscape" name="category[]" id="OptLandscape" />
  <label for="OptLandscape"> Landscape</label>     
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and selectFromDb.php file which uses this SELECT statement

```
 <? foreach($_GET['category'] as $category){
     $categories[] = $category;
   }
  $total_imgs_sql = "SELECT id, title, filePath FROM photos WHERE keyWords LIKE '%$category%'
 ?>
```

This returns the rows where any of the `$category` values exist in `keyWords`. I want to only return the rows `WHERE` **all** the $category keyWords exist.

How can this be achieved?
(The full version has nearly 200 checkboxes and each row could have around 20 comma separated words in `keyWords`)
Thanks

Comment: forgot a semicolon at end of SELECT statement

Comment: @Dharman: Important point but I am checking each $category against a whitelist and using mysqli, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by building a table of category values in your query, and then `JOIN`ing that to the `photos` table, and only selecting photos which return the same number of rows as are in the table of category values. As a sample query, to find photos with `Colour` and `Portrait` categories:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
  SELECT 'Colour' AS keyWord
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Portrait' AS keyWord
) k
JOIN photos p ON CONCAT(',', p.keyWords, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', k.keyWord, ',%')
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Query [demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eoxKcoFG6SwoW1gBY4Ti4u/0)

In PHP, you could generate this query like so:

```
$categories = array('Colour', 'Portrait');

$sql = "SELECT p.*\nFROM (\n  SELECT '";
$sql .= implode("' AS keyword\n  UNION ALL\n  SELECT '", $categories);
$sql .= "' AS keyWord\n) k\nJOIN photos p ON CONCAT(',', p.keyWords, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', k.keyWord, ',%')\n";
$sql .= "GROUP BY p.id\nHAVING COUNT(*) = " . count($categories);
```

PHP [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rR1Lm)

Note I've left in `\n` to make the output query match the above for readability; you can replace those with   (space).

Note also that you may be open to SQL injection, you should check the `$category` values to ensure they are valid (use a keyword whitelist), or convert to a prepared statement to avoid this. Here's how you can use a prepared statement (assuming you are using mysqli and your connection is in `$conn`):

```
$categories = array('Colour', 'Portrait');

$sql = "SELECT p.*\nFROM (\n  SELECT ";
$sql .= implode(" AS keyword\n  UNION ALL\n  SELECT ", array_fill(0, count($categories), '?'));
$sql .= " AS keyWord\n) k\nJOIN photos p ON CONCAT(',', p.keyWords, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', k.keyWord, ',%')\n";
$sql .= "GROUP BY p.id\nHAVING COUNT(*) = " . count($categories);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($categories)), ...$categories);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Note also that this would be simpler if you had `keywords` and `photo_keywords` tables with one line per photo/keyword combination in the latter, rather than using comma separated data (I would strongly suggest reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)).

Comment: @Dharman ran out of time, had to go to a meeting. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Dharman actually the question was originally tagged `mysqli`, I changed it to `mysql`

Comment: @Nick Thanks very much for your very generous help - plenty for me to chew on. Due to my inexperience it is going to take me a little time to comprehend your answer. If I get stuck (as I think I might!) I will comment here again.

Comment: @Cyclopic no worries - I hope this is useful. If you have any follow-up queries, please comment again and I will answer when I can.